# Cookies arent being tracked inside of <iframe>

Tags: authentication, cookies, iframe

I have a page with a iframe in it and in that iframe theres a login section after i login whenever i try to do something it asks me to login again

Iframe code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
 
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 700px;; overflow: hidden; top: -51px;
            }

            iframe
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: -51px; width: 100%; height: 700px;
            }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="tinted-image"></div>
    <iframe src="https://teampablotips.wixsite.com/pabloteam" style="border:none;" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

i have seen that i need to put `Set-Cookie: flavor=choco; SameSite=None;` somewhere but i dont know where`enter code here`

i know i need to set it so cookies work but im not sure how iv been looking for a while and i cant find a nooby enough answer since i dont know everything about website backend yet
if anyone could explain to me how do i fix this it would be appreciated